# Definition of $\sigma$-algebra. Axioms.

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, definition

""**Def.** A family $\mathcal F$ of subsets of $\Omega$ is said to be a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$ if:

(A.1) $\Omega\in\mathcal F$

(A.2) $\ A\in\mathcal F\implies\ A^c\in\mathcal F$

(A.3) $\ A_1,A_2,...\in\mathcal F\implies\bigcup _{n=1}^\infty A_n\in\mathcal F$

To make things work, need a bit more: namely, that we are allowed to take countable unions.""

I am struggling to understand what (A.3) is trying to say. Does $\bigcup _{n=1}^\infty A_n$ mean a union across all $\ A_n$? In addition, what is the significance of (A.3)? Are $\ A_n$ subsets of A? What are countable sets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each $A_n$ is a subset of $\Omega$. In the previous axiom we only needed to refer to one arbitrary set, so we just called it $A$. Now we want a collection of countably many arbitrary subsets $A_1,A_2, A_3,A_4,A_5,...$ so we need to label them somehow, and we do that via subscripts running over the natural numbers.

Now remember, a $\sigma$-algebra is a *collection of subsets* of $\Omega$ satisfying some rules. The rule that (A.3) captures is that if you take countably many subsets of $\Omega$ each of which are in $\mathcal{F}$ then the union (which is another subset of $\Omega$), is still a set in $\mathcal{F}$.

Does that help?

Comment: Ah, "a σ-algebra is a collection of subsets of Ω" some rules being the σ-algebra axioms or some function? Are $\ A_1,A_2,...$ disjoint? thank you! your explanations make complete sense! :)

Comment: @Brofessor: The rules are indeed the axioms. No the sets needn't be disjoint.

Comment: in addition i am aware that this statement has to hold (a.1) $\Omega\in\mathcal F$, would the power set take care of that statement? ie $\Omega= \{1,2,3\}\Rightarrow\mathcal F$ has a subset $\{1,2,3\}$

Comment: @Brofessor: again you're getting confused by the difference between elements and subsets in $\mathcal{F}$. If $\Omega =\{1,2,3\}$ and $\mathcal{F}$ is the powerset of $\Omega$, then one *element* of $\mathcal{F}$ is the set $\{1,2,3\}$ which is a *subset of* $\Omega$.