# Problem with σ-Algebra definition

Tags: probability, measure-theory

At the moment I'm doing my first steps in the probability theory but now I have some problems with the σ-Algebra. Here is the definition: $A \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ is called σ-Algebra if:

$
(1) \quad \Omega \in A \\
(2) \quad a \in A \implies a^C = \Omega \backslash A \in A \\
(3) \quad \forall a_1, a_2, ... \in A \implies \bigcup\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} a_n \in A
$

I have difficulties with the third theorem. How do I have to read it? Let's say I choose n = 2. Does it mean that I take 2 sets from A and the union of them must be in A? So mathematically:

$
a_1, a_2 \in A \\
a_3 = a_1 \cup a_2\\
a_3 \in A
$

Or have I missunderstood something here? In some definitions this is also used as the third theorem:

$\quad \forall a_1, a_2, ... \in A \implies \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \in A$

So are these theorems the same? Because with this my theorie from above does not work. Would be great if you can help me with this.

Comment: The two versions of property (3) mean the same thing. You're misunderstanding one of them - I _suspect_ that you're understanding the second version correctly.

Comment: You would expect that if two different sets are in the $\sigma$-algebra then the union of those two sets would in the $\sigma$-algebra, no?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1075191/definition-of-sigma-algebra-axioms

Comment: Something that you may have missed : Note that as $\emptyset$ is in $A$, 3) also imply that finite unions are in $A$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, they are not "theorems" but statements that make up the "definition" of a $\sigma$-algebra.

You are right, if $a_1, a_2 \in A \implies a_1 \cup a_2 \in A$ (this can be seen by considering $a_k = \emptyset$ for $k \ge 3$); but the crucial difference between an algebra and a $\sigma$-algebra (and the whole reason why it's called $\sigma$) is that you can take a *countable* number of sets in $A$ and be sure that their union is still in $A$. This is a stronger requirement that just the finite union of sets.

Also note that thanks to the second requirement, you also have $a_1 \cap a_2 \in A$ as well as $\cap_{n=1}^\infty a_n \in A$. Basically any (countable or finite) union or intersection of sets in $A$ must be in $A$.

Finally, $\displaystyle \cup _{n = 1}^\infty$ and $\displaystyle \cup_{\mathbb N}$ mean the same thing; you have a (countable) collection of sets $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ and you take the union of all of them

Comment: those are not "axioms" either, they are part of a "definition." Example: DEFINITION: Two lines are parallel if their intersection is empty. (That is a CONDITION in the definition). AXIOM: Given a line in a plane and a point in the same plane, with the point not on the line, there is a line through that point, parallel to the given line. Conditions in a definition are NOT axioms.

Comment: @mathguy uhm, I see your point..  :)

Answer (score 0):

The expression reads that if there is a countable set of sets all of which are in $A$, then the union of them is in $A$. The bounds on the union are $n\in\Bbb{N}$, i.e. you take the union of $a_n$ for every $n\in\Bbb{N}$. This is equivalent to the bounds in "$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty$", or you may sometimes see "$\bigcup_{n\ge 1}$", as well.

Note that these sets need not be distinct: indeed, in order to show that $a_1\cup a_2\in A$, you can consider the countable sequence of sets $a_1, a_2, a_2, a_2, \ldots$ (so you let $a_i=a_2$ for *all* $i\ge 2$).

We know that for every set $X\cup X=X$, so $a_2\cup a_2=a_2$, etc. The third property of a $\sigma$-algebra tells you that

\begin{align}\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb{N}} a_n\in A & \Rightarrow a_1\cup a_2\cup a_3\cup\dots\in A\\
&\Rightarrow a_1\cup (a_2\cup a_3\cup a_4\cup\dots)\in A\\
&\Rightarrow a_1\cup (a_2\cup a_2\cup a_2\cup\dots)\in A\\
&\Rightarrow a_1\cup a_2\in A.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are asking, but...   FIRST, those are conditions in a definition; "theorem" means something very different. SECOND, condition (3) means that given any COUNTABLY INFINITE collection of members of $A$, their union must also belong to $A$. For example, this is satisfied trivially if $A$ is ALL of ${\cal P}(\Omega)$. On the other hand, it is not satisfied if $\Omega = \mathbb R$ and $A$ consists of all the finite subsets of $\mathbb R$ and the complements of all finite subsets (although this family of subsets does satisfy (1) and (2) and a weaker form of 3, where only unions of FINITELY MANY members of $A$ are required to be in $A$).

If (1), (2) and (3) are true, then (THEOREM!) the union of finitely many members of $A$ is also always in $A$. To prove this, first note that condition (2) implies that the empty set is in $A$ (because $\Omega$ is in $A$ by condition (1)). Now you can take any finite union and make it countably infinite by adding countably many copies of the empty set to the union.